# If elif else statements in python

Tags: python

I'm writing some python where user reads a few options from a list with available products and in the input field types the letter of the product that wants to buy. Part of the code that doesn't work as I wish has as follow:

```
a=int(input('Choose a product: '))
if a=='A':
    print('Product A have been chosen')
elif a=='B':
    print('Product B have been chosen')
else:
    print('Print something else')
```

The problem is that the program doesn't recognise the letter A and provides an error rather to print user's selection. I try the same code:

1. with single quotations
2. with double quotations
3. without quotations
4. and at last I mixed some and/or statements which didn't work but actually I wouldn't like to involve and/or statements, if that possible.

The code works perfectly if instead of letters let the user type numbers. What do I miss, I'm not sure to tell.

OK! I remove the int and type plain input and it works nice:

```
a=input('Choose a prodcut: ')
```

instead of:

```
a=int(input('Choose a product: '))
```

Comment: Why do you think that `a` will ever contain anything other than an `int`?

Comment: @ignacio input with int reads only numbers. Input without int reads both numbers and letters, if I'm not mistaken.

Answer (score 0):

You're converting the user input into an integer -

```
a=int(input('Choose a product: '))
```

And then you're trying to check if the integer is equal to a character -

```
if a=='A':
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, you're converting the input to an `int`, so it obviously can't be the letter "A" - so you should drop the `int` from there. Also, note that in python 2.x, `input` attempts to evaluate the input it receives, and you should probably use `raw_input` instead:

```
a = raw_input('Choose a product: ')
```

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
a=int(input('Choose a product: '))
```

Stores an integer, it will never be equal to 'A' or 'B'. Change it to

```
a=input('Choose a product: ')
```

Answer (score 0):

`a=int(input("Please Enter a value"))`
This means you want `a` to hold an `integer` and you convert the input to `integer` which is why

```
a=int(input(1)) //this works
a=int(input(2.45))//this will work will only return 2
```

But

```
a=int(input("a"))//will give you an error since a can not be converted to a number 
//The values inside brackets are just to demonstrate an example of what you may enter as input`
```

To make this work for Characters and Strings just make

```
a=input("please enter value")
```